Firefox profile disaster
I had to wipe my laptop as my Ubuntu 20.04 installation was getting messy. I followed the official instructions about Firefox profiles and backed up the folder containing my profile.
Then I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and now I can't load this old profile. The instructions simply don't work.
I'm not sure if my old installation was snap or not, but now that's not possible to check as I wiped the laptop.
If I open compatibility.ini in the old profile there is this value:
LastVersion=128.0_20240704121409/20240704121409

I'm sure I'm putting the profile in the correct folder: ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/
So it seems I've lost all my passwords, extensions data and history.
Are the official instructions on how to transfer profiles wrong? Is there some other way to get my data back? I'm feeling pretty desperate here :(

Your question is confusing. You talk about a version of Ubuntu and restoring a profile and then talk about Firefox. Please edit the question and make it clear what you are asking.

are the profile files from different package formats ie .deb and snap and did you first create your profile in FF? I've done this many times successfully and just relogged in to my FF account on the new instance (.deb, snap and Flatpak versions alike)  and voila! Never needed to copy any profile files over...

Snap Firefox profiles are in a different location than deb Firefox profiles. So "same version of Firefox that I had before" is not specific enough. Your question should specify exactly what installed and how you did it.

@DavidDE I updated my question. I hope it's more clear now.

@graham so you just copied old profile into ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/ and it worked? Sadly this is not the case for me.

Did you follow exactly Restoring to a different location in your link?

No, I created a FF account and logged in to that account on the new instances. That's the whole point of setting up an account.

@amar yes I think so. It's basically just taking contents from old profile and pasting into the new profile. This also didn't work.

@graham I didn't know such a feature exists. Why don't they mention this in the backup/restore instructions?

Hit the hamburger menu to create your account. When you install a new instance, it prompts you to log in to your account.

@graham yeah, but it's too late now. I should have done this before wiping Ubuntu 20.04, right?

yup, but do it now for future installations

yeah, but I still didn't lose hope. There must be a way to restore my old profile. Is it possible that official documentation doesn't work and there is nothing we can do?

I went from windows to Ubuntu and copied my profile as described in the link, had no problem. Try https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/xh1zqy/transferring_profiles_not_workingerrors/ but do a backup first

I've copied profiles between Ubuntu systems and, regularly backup my firefox profiles.  All firefox profiles are found in
~/.mozilla/firefox

It's not necessary to backup all the profiles found there.  Rather than accept a default name, I choose the names of my firefox profiles.
Introducing a profile to firefox is done with the command  firefox -P
Using a profile other than the default profile is done with the command
firefox -P *profile*

I do not use a SNAP installed firefox.

How do you install non-snap firefox? I tried apt install firefox, but this also does the snap install.

@user568021 https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/158442

I depend upon firefox a lot.  In the past years there has been multiple instances where a firefox change has been a problem - fixed but in the mean time a real problem.  This said, firefox is one of the very few packages I manually maintain.  As a result, it takes only a few seconds for me to revert to a previous version.  I'll explain how I do this in the next few comments.

Rather than uninstall the official version of firefox,  I set it aside (/usr/bin/firefox is renamed /usr/bin/firefoxSNAP).  A symbolic link is set at /usr/bin/firefox (ln -s /usr/lib/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox)

I obtain the current firefox directly from "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/" I untar the file, which results in a directory structure.  I then change ownership and group to root (for protection as I have a multi-user system). I then set aside the /usr/lib/firefox directory (example sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox125).  Finally I move the new firefox directory structure to /usr/lib/firefox

This also provides my backout plan - sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox128 followed by sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox125 /usr/lib/firefox    If you're going backward on a firefox release, you will need to one time start it with the command  firefox --allow-downgrade
